# Swift not managing to call draw(GRect) more than once

Tags: swift

I am trying to learn swift bu it seems I am already stuck.
Can someone point out why the `{ didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }` does not seem to work?!
The goal is to draw a small circle where the user taps
Here is my Controller:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var display: UIView!{

    didSet{

        display.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addCirclePoint(byReactingTo:))))

    }

}

  let pointsAndLines = PointsAndLinesView()

  func addCirclePoint(byReactingTo tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let point = tapRecognizer.location(in: display)
        pointsAndLines.point = point

  }

}
```

And here is my View:

```
 import UIKit


class PointsAndLinesView: UIView {

var point = CGPoint(){ didSet{ setNeedsDisplay() } }


private func addCirclePoint()->UIBezierPath{

    let circlePoint = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: point, radius: 5.0, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    circlePoint.lineWidth = 4
    print("Did I run?!")
    return circlePoint

}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    UIColor.black.set()

    addCirclePoint().stroke()

}
```

}

Looking forward to your responses.

**EDIT:**

For future reference in case someone needs it the mistake was,

that display is a subclass of PointsAndLinesView and NOT of UIView

and display.point should be set.

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't `setNeedsDisplay` take a `bool` argument?

Comment: No bool needed.  If empty the entire view is invalidated but you can pass a CGRect to invalidate a region of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you have never added the pointsAndLines control to a view so you will never see it.  You can add it as a subview of the main view and then set it's frame manually or use auto layout to position it.

Comment: The draw method executes once, and I see one circle. I also get the location of the tap. I can not redraw.

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the pointsAndLines property to a view.  If I add it and size it then it works correctly for me.  Also make sure user interaction is enabled for the display view.